# How can we remove the renditions from the renditions list

Tags: content-hub

In Content Hub how can we remove the renditions from the Renditions list on the Asset detail page that were deleted from media processing?

I have already tried refreshing renditions with all options, but it is not removing them from the rendition list.

```
CH Version :  "4.0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete the renditions already created from the Asset details page along with deleting the rendition from the Media Processing flow you will have to delete it from the M.Renditionlink as well by following the steps.
Mangange -> Entities-> M.RenditionLink-> look for the desired rendition and then click on details. You would see the delete button on the right hand side top